# omniauth behind proxy

Tags: ruby, sinatra, omniauth

I have a small app using omniauth and I'm testing it with LinkedIn provider (omniauth-linkedin). Unfortunately my test environment is behind a proxy. So I need to access linkedin through a proxy.

How do I set the proxy address so the request to linkedin will succeed? It does not seem to be obeying the http_proxy settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, I think..

```
ue OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedin, "KEY", "SECRET", {:client_options => { :proxy =>\
 ENV["HTTP_PROXY"] || ENV["http_proxy"]  }}
end
```